# HTTP 400 error while trying to make a POST call with upload file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, axios, blob

I have an endpoint related to file upload defined in the Java controller as below;

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload/file", method = { RequestMethod.POST})
public MyResponse<?> uploadFile(@RequestHeader(required = true) String country, @RequestHeader(required = true) String user, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
{
}
```

I am trying to invoke this from the UI as below;

```
const response = await MyReactUtility.postMultipartFileContent(endpoint, result);

postMultipartFileContent(url, data) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", data.files[0]);
    return axios.post(url, formData).catch(err => console.log("Axios multipart err: ", err));
},
```

My "data" param passed to above "postMultipartFileContent" looks as below;
[image]

In Chrome Network tab, I can see Payload as;

```
Form Data
    file: (binary)
```

However, I am seeing 400 Bad Request error.

Comment: you should turn on the logs to debug level in order to see the reason spring boot app is sending you the 400 (you can do it with for example setting `logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG` in `application.properties`).

If i have to guess I would say that you are not sending the headers that you marked as required - you can try setting them as `required = false` and see if that helps - but this is just a guess, please turn on and check the logs

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be related to the headers or the way you are handling the file in your frontend.
Try this:

```
const response = await MyReactUtility.postMultipartFileContent(endpoint, result);

postMultipartFileContent(url, data) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", data.files[0]);
    return axios.post(url, formData, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'country': 'your_country_value', // Replace with actual country value
            'user': 'your_user_value' // Replace with actual user value
        }
    }).catch(err => console.log("Axios multipart err: ", err));
}
```

You can change the value use according to your need.